# How to use capistrano for a non-rails app? just a static html site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have been using capistrano on a rails site, and to set it up I just did the usual:

```
capify .
```

Now how could I use this on a static html site to publish?

Comment: I found this as a helpful resource: http://nubyonrails.com/articles/using-capistrano-with-perl-or-php

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [railsless-deploy](https://github.com/leehambley/railsless-deploy/) gem.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is a Capfile. I copied the relevant parts from a non-static site and use it for my static site. Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/821925).